# Copy and Pasting the Cell Values from one sheet to another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

When i press the run button `Target.Address = "$B$6" Then` cell is update to trigger the below code.

I have been using below code which i run first time it copies the cell value from `sht2 B4` and paste into `sht3 B4`.

**2nd time runs the code it copies the `sht2 Q4` and paste into `sht3 C4`.**

3rd time runs the code it copies the `sht2 B4` and paste into `sht3 D4`.

4th time runs the code it copies the `sht2 B4` and paste into `sht3 E4`.

5th time runs the code it copies the `sht2 B4` and paste into `sht3 F4`.

6th time runs the code it copies the `sht2 B4` and paste into `sht3 G4`.

**7th time runs the code it copies the `sht2 Q4` and paste into `sht3 H4`.**

8th time runs the code it copies the `sht2 B4` and paste into `sht3 I4`. and it is working perfectly i have attached a workbook which can be download and might be better for understanding.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim col As Long
Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

col = sht3.Cells(4, sht3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
If col = 3 Or 8 Then
    sht2.Cells(4, 17).copy
Else
    sht2.Cells(4, 2).copy
End If
sht3.Cells(4, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If
End Sub
```

and i want same thing for 2nd Table that is

1st time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 F4` and paste into `sht3 L4`

**2nd time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 U4` and paste into `sht3 M4`**

3rd time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 F4` and paste into `sht3 N4`

4th time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 F4` and paste into `sht3 O4`

5th time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 F4` and paste into `sht3 P4`

6th time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 F4` and paste into `sht3 Q4`

**7th time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 U4` and paste into `sht3 R4`**

8th time runs the code it will copy the `sht2 F4` and paste into `sht3 S4`

so i tried and make below piece of code and added it with above code, where code for 1st table was working fine but 2nd Table is not updating the values and no error occurs.

```
col2 = sht3.Cells(4, sht3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 13
   If col2 = 12 Or col2 = 17 Then
       sht2.Cells(4, 21).copy
    Else
      sht2.Cells(4, 6).copy
    End If
    sht3.Cells(4, col2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Any help to solve the problem will be greatly appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JIrRMdoexFS2QyoaTX6_yDw31muEEFTf/view?usp=sharing

Sht3 picture
[image]

Comment: `sht3.Cells(4, sht3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` will never get past the green-shaded cells

Comment: Yes you are right. Than how to pass the green shaded cells that is the main problem.

Comment: `sht3.Cells(4, "J").End(xlToLeft)`  for the orange-shaded cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe (untested):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long, i As Long
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    If Target.Address = "$B$6" Then
        'run 8 times....
        For i = 1 To 8
        
            col = sht3.Cells(4, "J").End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            
            sht3.Cells(4, col).Value = IIf(col = 3 Or col = 8, sht2.Cells(4, 17).Value, _
                                                               sht2.Cells(4, 2).Value)
            
            col = sht3.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
            If col < 12 Then col = 12  'min column for green-shaded area
        
            sht3.Cells(4, col).Value = IIf(col = 12 Or col = 17, sht2.Cells(4, 21).Value, _
                                                                 sht2.Cells(4, 6).Value)
       Next i

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very very much @Tim Williams

Comment: It is exactly what i have been looking for so long. Thank you.

Comment: is there a way that i press the button once and all values will get loaded automatically in sht3 rather than running the code 8th time. @Tim Williams

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `Worksheet_Change` event for this?  Why not just a regular Sub?

Comment: Yes there is a reason behind that is whenever i press the Run button Sheet1 Range B6 is update with new ID then Worksheets change functions run i have set a trigger.

Comment: But if you have it fill all 8 slots then it can only run once?  And it always does the same thing?  It's difficult to make adjustments without some context around why you're doing this.

Comment: Yes i want to run it once after that all 8 slot's should be filled but currently i run the code 8th time to fill each slot one by one. That is not good approach to run the code 8th time to fill each slot separately.

Comment: But you can only ever run it once?  Do the cells being copied always have a value?  What happens when the slots on Sheet3 are full ?

Comment: Actually no, I am taking about other code which is available in Module 1. Which i run one by one 8th time to paste the result in 8 cells. Yes those cells which being copied always have different value. If the Sheet3 slots are full then cose will stop.

Comment: OK see my edit above - just put the steps in a loop for 8 iterations...

Comment: Thank you once again for the help Sir.